# Access to file is denied when LINQ is used instead of a foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I get **this exception**:

> {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
>   {"Access to the path 'C:\test\test\bin\log' is denied."}

When I run this code:

```
if(Directory.Exists(logPath))
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(logPath, "*.log")
                    .Select(file => File.ReadAllText(logPath))
                    .ToList();
}
```

I get **NO** exception when I run this code:

```
if(Directory.Exists(logPath))
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    var filesPath = Directory.GetFiles(logPath, "*.log");
    foreach (var filePath in filesPath)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        list.Add(text);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Why can I not use Linq to get the text files content?

Comment: Shouldn't the first one be `.Select(file => File.ReadAllText(file))` ?

Comment: @Rotem That should be the answer IMHO

Comment: Thanks Rotem that was my bug...

Comment: we are going to need the rest of the code, needless to say, something else is causing your exception.

Comment: welcome to 7 minutes ago @Jodrell

Comment: check whether you have permission to access that folder..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your both code should be same. This would also not throw exception.

`.Select(file => File.ReadAllText(file))`

**Full Code**

```
if (Directory.Exists(logPath))
       {
           return Directory
               .GetFiles(logPath, "*.log")
               .Select(file => File.ReadAllText(file))
               .ToList();
       }
```

**Please Note:** Your Exception is not LINQ specific.

Comment: I think the exception was due to calling `ReadAllText` on a directory, this should now not throw an exception if the `foreach` version wasn't.

Comment: +1 The poster deserves as much rep as possible for copying his answer from a comment by someone else, introducing a mistake which shows he didn't fully understand what he was copying.

Comment: A bit unfair to earn rep on this IMHO. @Rotem deserves the kudos here.

Comment: @jwg What's the difference? This is a non-question, which was obviously going to be closed in seconds.

Comment: @Rotem, yes, and the answerer will keep the reputation he has earned when it is.

Comment: @jwg If it were important to me I should have posted an answer rather than a comment.